Why do we need backslashes here in this piped logging configuration for Apache Httpd Server?
The configuration line is CustomLog "|$/bin/sed -u -E \'s/(ticket)(=|%3D)[a-zA-Z0-9%]+/\\\1\\\2***/g\' >> /dev/stdout" json. The goal is to replace query params like ticket=123 to ticket=***.
I've tried without \'s, \', \\\. None of them work.
The questions are:

Why do we need \'s and \'? The ' is inside ", Isn't it unnecessary to do so?
Why do we need \\\ instead of just \\? I thought the first backslash is in the context of Apache configuration to escape the following backslash so that \\ actually becomes \ when passed to the shell indicated by $ in the beginning.


The issue does not come from defining the string in the first place, but from handing the content over from shell to shell. Inbetween the steps the string is interpreted by the executing shell. You need to suppress that interpretation so that the arguments reach the sed command unmodified. So uninterpreted by the shell.

@arkascha You mean there are multiple shells here?

My phrasing was unprecise, sorry for that. I actually cannot say if there are multiple shells involved here. But for certain one when piping log entries into the sed utility and redirecting the outcome into the file. That might not be a "shell" in the classical sense of an interactive bash or similar. But a forked process accepting and processing command line arguments. Which is the step typically responsible for such neccessities.
